# What Font is used here?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

Any idea what's the font used here? (Spring Summer '16).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: will you trying vani bold font.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Please review [our guidelines for font-identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083/19174) and [edit] your question accordingly, lest it be closed.

Answer (score 1):

This poster uses Adobe Caslon Pro Semibold:

[image: 'Spring 16' written in the font]